# GDI+ does not follow the LAYOUT_RTL of the used HDC

Tags: gdi+, gdi, win32gui

All items we draw with the old GDI use the underlying layout direction of the Window. The windows are created with WS_EX_RTLLAYOUT. Windows perfectly move the Filled rects from the left side on an LTR system to the right side of the Window when running on a Hebrew system. 
As soon we use GDI+ on the same HDC nothing happens. All stays LTR. Of course we can start calculating ourselves where the rect should appear on the screen, however, this works half. The area we then paint in is not invalid and so painting gets clipped.

Any suggestions concerning this issue are very much appreciated.
Jasper de Keijzer

Answer (score 0):

The layout is a property of the window, not the graphics layer.  It's the program's responsibility to check the layout and do the right thing.

What you're seeing with GDI is that, to help programs, Windows reverses the DC's default coordinate mapping for a right-to-left window, so the coordinates change.

GDI+ must either override that or do its own coordinate mapping.  This isn't surprising, since GDI+ can use floating point coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by letting GDI+ paint into a memory device context and later I blit this to the screen. For the blitting I use the standard GDI functions and this gives me the Right to left back.

As an example I submit here my code which is use to create a gradient filled area. The code runs now on a LTR and RTL environment and this means we do not have two code bases for the difference in direction.

```
long srvDrawGradientFilledRect(HDC hdc,LPRECT lpFillingRect,
                               unsigned long startcolor, unsigned long endcolor, UINT uFlags)
{
    BYTE red_end, red_start;
    BYTE green_end, green_start;
    BYTE blue_end, blue_start;
    RECT FillingRect = *lpFillingRect;
    int xSize;
    int ySize;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    xSize = (FillingRect.right - FillingRect.left);
    ySize = (FillingRect.bottom - FillingRect.top);
    xPos = FillingRect.left;
    yPos = FillingRect.top;
    // Create compatible device context.
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    // Create compatible bitmap.
    HBITMAP hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, xSize, ySize);
    // Select bitmap into device context.  (Bitmap holds all changes drawn in its DC.)
    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);
    // endcolor in bytes
    blue_end = (BYTE)(endcolor >> 16);
    green_end = (BYTE)(endcolor >> 8);
    red_end = (BYTE)(0x000000FF & endcolor);
    // startcolor in bytes
    blue_start = (BYTE)(startcolor >> 16);
    green_start = (BYTE)(startcolor >> 8);
    red_start = (BYTE)(0x000000FF & startcolor);

    LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush(Point(0, 0),       // starting point of the gradient
                                   Point(0, ySize),    // ending point of the gradient
                                   Color(255, red_start, green_start, blue_start),       // White starting color
                                   Color(255, red_end, green_end, blue_end));   // End color
    Graphics graphics(hdcMem);
    graphics.SetCompositingMode(CompositingModeSourceCopy);
    graphics.FillRectangle(&linGrBrush,0,0,xSize,ySize);
    // a box is painted arround the gradient in the end color.
    if (uFlags & ODRW_GRADIENT_OUTLINE) {
        Pen pen(Color(255, red_end, green_end, blue_end), 1.0f);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(&pen, 0, 0, xSize - 1, ySize);
    }
    BitBlt(hdc, FillingRect.left, FillingRect.top, xSize, ySize, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    /* Cleanup*/
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    return 1;
}
```

Hope this helps in solving RTL problems in conjunction with GDI+.

If there are better ways to solve this issue, please let me know.

Jasper